# Can't select files or folders in dialog box

Tags: mouse, folders, file, dialog

Every time I want to save or open a file from any program (Chrome, Keynote, Numbers, Safari,...) on my 2021 MBP, when the dialog box opens I can't click on any of the folders or files, nor can I click on the filename for changing it. I can only press Tab, the arrow keys and Enter on my keyboard to move around, although this doesn't work correctly.

What kind of bug am I having?

Update: After restarting, the problem dissappeared, but after a few days sleeping (and waking) the computer, the problem has returned. I run Chrome, Anaconda Navigator, YouTube (app), YT Music (app), Keynote, Notes and agenda as apps. The problem occurs in Chrome, Keynote when trying to open or save a file.

Update 2: I attach a screenshot. I cannot click on any of the (activated) buttons or folders etc. Cmd+1/2/3 still works (as using Tab and Esc).

[image]

Comment: Does this happen always or only sometimes? If you create a new user account on your Mac and try there, does it also happen?

Comment: Can you get a screenshot? Does pressing Cmd/1 [or 2 or 3] change the view? Can you see what folder the dialog is in?

Comment: After a few restarts and closing all applications, I cannot reproduce this error. Will update if I encounter it again. Thanks.

Comment: Does this only happen in GoogleDrive?

Comment: No, I just show this folder because it doesn't show any personal stuff. I changed the view by using Tab and arrow keys

Comment: just got the same issue - will try with restarting. it's worth noticing that keyboard navigation still works, so press tab 2 times and you're in the main window, then you can select things with the arrow keys